# Android Navigation Drawer with fragments that open other sub fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I'm developing an Android app (I'm a newbie) that uses a Navigation Drawer. I've created multiple fragments that represent the various item in the side menu. One of them has a RecyclerView, and I want to show another fragment with various details when the user clicks one of the item of the RecyclerView.

I've created the structure successfully, implement the click listener on the RecyclerView item, but I don't know how to show the details fragment (and how to go back from it).

If showing another fragment is not the right way, please suggest me the best way to obtain the navigation that I need.

CODE

MenuActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
```

MenuActivity.kt

```
class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

val vendutoFragment = VendutoFragment()
val prezziFragment = PrezziFragment()
val giacenzeFragment = GiacenzeFragment()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        addFragment(vendutoFragment)
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(nav_venduto)
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    var selectedFragment = Fragment()
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_venduto -> {
            selectedFragment = vendutoFragment
        }
        R.id.nav_prezzi -> {
            selectedFragment = prezziFragment
        }
        R.id.nav_giacenze -> {
            selectedFragment = giacenzeFragment
        }
    }

    replaceFragment(selectedFragment)

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}

private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit()
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit()
}
```

}

1st Fragment with RecyclerView and clickable item

```
class GiacenzeFragment: Fragment(){
var global: Global? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
{
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_giacenze, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    activity!!.title = "Giacenze"
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    giacenzeTable.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?

    global = getActivity()?.getApplication() as Global

    // Access the RecyclerView Adapter and load the data into it
    giacenzeTable.adapter = GiacenzeTableAdapter(global!!.prodotti, { prodotto: Prodotto -> prodottoItemClicked(prodotto) })
}

private fun prodottoItemClicked(prodotto: Prodotto)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked: ${prodotto.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    var serbatoiFrag =  SerbatoiFragment()
    serbatoiFrag.idProdotto = prodotto.idProdotto
    serbatoiFrag.nameProdotto = prodotto.name

    fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()!!.replace(R.id.frameLayout, serbatoiFrag).commit()

}
```

}

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to load fragment in a new activity, just open new activity and use replaceFragment
if you want to load in same activity, just use replaceFragment
do you know how to use [replaceFragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui)?

Comment: Not so well. Is it ok if I call it inside the clicklistener of the first fragment?         fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()!!.replace(R.id.frameLayout, VendutoFragment()).commit()

Comment: I've added the code. It's working but I'm not sure how to come back to the previous fragment.